# How to know it's loading with async & ngFor

Tags: angular, rxjs, apollo

I am following apollo angular guide for using async in ngFor directive: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/queries.html#rxjs

I found way to check for no data:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="something.length; else nothing"></ng-container>
```

But I can't seem to find a way to display a loading spinner while data are being loaded.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
*ngIf = "data | async as something; else loading"
```

Code in the guide:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Apollo} from 'apollo-angular';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const FeedQuery = gql`
  query Feed {
    currentUser {
      login
    }
    feed {
      createdAt
      score
    }
  }
`;

@Component({
  template: `
    <ul *ngFor="let entry of data | async">
      Score: {{entry.score}}
    </ul>
  `,
})
class FeedComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.apollo
      .watchQuery({query: FeedQuery})
      .valueChanges.pipe(map(({data}) => data.feed));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you just try putting `data | async` into parenthesis like `(data | async) as something; else loading`

Comment: Actually the chain won't emit until `.valueChanges` emits so you should maybe initialize the chain with eg. `startWith`: `....valueChanges.pipe(map(...), startWith(false));`

Comment: NICE. It worked with a bit of tweaking and I can use ngIf, I'll write down the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As martin mentioned in the comment, the solution is to simply initialize the chain with something else until it loads, so we can test this value in our template.

The obvious one is null.

```
  .valueChanges.pipe(
    map(({ data }) => data.feed),
    startWith(null),
  );
```

Then in the code, you can use a simple ngIf to check if it's loading or not.

```
<h1 *ngIf="(data | async) == null">Loading</h1>
```

That way we can still check for empty (since it will be an empty array, not null)

Brilliant. Thanks.